# iOS broadcast memory leak

Tags: ios, replaykit

I am testing ReplayKit broadcast extension with instruments. I fixed some leaks on my extension, but some of leaks happens on Framework side and I cannot find a way to resolve. Anyone knows how to fix?
It leaks 48Kbyte every .5 sec.

I checked History of the memory address. Retain delta is +0.
Retain and Release is well paired including these functions,

```
[_NSPlaceholderData initWithBytes:length:copy:deallocator:]
[NSXPCDecoder _decodeArrayOfObjectsForKey:]_block_invoke  
[RPBroadcastSampleHandler _processPayloadWithAudioSample:type:]_block_invoke
[RPBroadcastSampleHandler _audioBufferListFromData:]
```

My processSampleBuffer() returns immediately for testing. So leak is not happens my processSampleBuffer().

[Screenshot of Xcode instruments](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sI64J.jpg)

Answer (score 1):

This stack log is taken by Zombies instruments. Zombies changes debuggee's behavior of autorelease(), it keep the auto-released object.

By comparing Zombies instruments result with Allocations instruments result,  I found the auto-released object is freed on Allocations. So memory leak is not happens on the object.